# Rotating image and load to MXNet model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, mxnet, gluon

Is there a way to load a image, rotate it and load it to MXNet model (e.g: yolov3).
I use the below method but I don't think it's efficient:
1/ Load the image and rotate it with pillow

```
image = Image.open(img_path)
image = image.rotate(90)
```

2/ Save the image and then load it with `gluoncv` (I use yolo here so I used yolo.load_test):

```
#Save image
image.save(name +".png")

#Load image with gluoncv 
imgs_for_inference, imgs_for_plot = gluoncv.data.transforms.presets.yolo.load_test(
   images_names,
   short=512)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some libraries, I found a more simple method for the problem without the need to save image and then load it (which is very inefficent). I used pillow to load the image and rotate it, then use transform_test to get MXNet tensor so as to feed to the model:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(path_to_image)
image = image.rotate(90)
tensor, _ = gluoncv.data.transforms.presets.yolo.transform_test(
    images,
    short=512
  )
prediction = model(tensor)
```