# How to rotate an image using only the mxnet ndarray and contrib.nd.array APIs?

Tags: python, arrays, mxnet

## How to rotate an image using only the mxnet ndarray and contrib.nd.array APIs

I'm trying to rotate an image using base mxnet array api.  I also trying to avoid using code which breaks the mxnet pipeline.  [eg.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049725/rotating-image-and-load-to-mxnet-model)

Perhaps this is pedantic, but its also an exercise in learning the api.  With that said, here is my question in detail.

(NOTE: I originally did this without batch axes, but I readded the batch axes to make it more similar to contrib api example.)

## Given a simple 2x2 pixel "image" represented as so:

```
# batch 1
in_data = nd.arange(4).reshape((1,2,2))
print('in_data is ', in_data)

>output
in_data is  
[[[0. 1.]
  [2. 3.]]]
<NDArray 1x2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## Create an array for output. put all nines as pixel values

```
# setup an ouptut array with all nines, so I can see overwrites with new values
out_data = nd.ones(4).reshape((2,2))*9
# out_data also needs to be in batch form
out_data = nd.expand_dims(out_data, axis=0)
print('out_data is ', out_data)

out_data is  
[[[9. 9.]
  [9. 9.]]]
<NDArray 1x2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## setup a rotate array

```
# setup a rotation matrix
rotate_data = rotate_90
print('rotate_90 ', rotate_data)


rotate_90  
[[ 6.123234e-17 -1.000000e+00]
 [ 1.000000e+00  6.123234e-17]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## Build an iterator and rotate the image indexes

```
# NDArrayIter(data, label=None, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, 
#            last_batch_handle='pad', data_name='data', 
#            label_name='softmax_label')
#
# Ignore the label parameter.
dataiter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(in_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, last_batch_handle='discard')
#batch_index = [0]
for batch in dataiter:
    print('loop entry - a single batch - a single image in batch.data[0] from what is in in_data')
    #print ('batch.data[0] = ', batch.data[0].asnumpy())
    #print ('batch.data[0].shape = ', batch.data[0].shape)
    # Does this copy or get an alias to the input image?
    input_img = batch.data[0]
    #print ('input_img = ', input_img.asnumpy())
    print ('input_img.shape = ', input_img.shape)
    
    # this will print the axis including the batch axis
    # print('indicies are ', mx.nd.contrib.index_array(entire_img) )
    # this will print the x,y axis and ignore the batch
    input_img_indexes = mx.nd.contrib.index_array(input_img, axes=(1, 2))
    #print('indexes are: ', input_img_indexes)
    #print ('input_img_indexes.shape = ', input_img_indexes.shape)
    
    
    # copy data from input to output
    # Note, this seems to also use the batch axis?  Its shape (1,2,2)
    #out_data = input_img
    
    # Try to assign input data to output data based upon indicies
    orig_indexes = mx.nd.reshape(input_img_indexes, shape=(4,2))
    #print('new_indexes ', new_indexes)
    orig_indexes = orig_indexes.astype("float32")
    
    # I've seen one variant where matrix-matrix multiply 
    # is done with .T.  why?
    new_indexes = nd.dot(orig_indexes, rotate_data) 
    #print('result = ', result)
    new_indexes = new_indexes.astype('int64')
    print('new_indexes = ', new_indexes)
    new_indexes = new_indexes + nd.array(nd.array([0, 1])).astype('int64')
    print('new_indexes after shift to positive', new_indexes)
    


loop entry - a single batch - a single image in batch.data[0] from what is in in_data
input_img.shape =  (1, 2, 2)
new_indexes =  
[[ 0  0]
 [ 1  0]
 [ 0 -1]
 [ 1 -1]]
<NDArray 4x2 @cpu(0)>
new_indexes after shift to positive 
[[0 1]
 [1 1]
 [0 0]
 [1 0]]
<NDArray 4x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## Dump the ins and outs

```
print('out_data is ', out_data)
print('in_data is ', in_data)
print('rotate_data is ', rotate_data)
print('orig_indexes is ', orig_indexes)
print('new_indexes is ', new_indexes)
print('new_indexes.dtype is ', new_indexes.dtype)

out_data is  
[[[9. 9.]
  [9. 9.]]]
<NDArray 1x2x2 @cpu(0)>
in_data is  
[[[0. 1.]
  [2. 3.]]]
<NDArray 1x2x2 @cpu(0)>
rotate_data is  
[[ 6.123234e-17 -1.000000e+00]
 [ 1.000000e+00  6.123234e-17]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
orig_indexes is  
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 1.]]
<NDArray 4x2 @cpu(0)>
new_indexes is  
[[0 1]
 [1 1]
 [0 0]
 [1 0]]
<NDArray 4x2 @cpu(0)>
new_indexes.dtype is  <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

## And now the reason I am asking for your help

At this point, I muddled about a bunch.  Then I went back to pen and paper.  Here is description of my problem now and why I am here.

[image]

## Back to the code

### rewriting to match notes

To avoid the batch dimension, and simplfy problem

## the orig image

```
orig_image = in_data[0]
print('orig_image ', orig_image)

orig_image  
[[0. 1.]
 [2. 3.]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## the rotated image memory for output

```
rotated_image=out_data[0]
print('rotated_image', rotated_image)

rotated_image 
[[9. 9.]
 [9. 9.]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## The original indexes/indices

```
print('orig_indexes', orig_indexes)

orig_indexes 
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 1.]]
<NDArray 4x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## The new indices

```
print('new_indexes', new_indexes)

new_indexes 
[[0 1]
 [1 1]
 [0 0]
 [1 0]]
<NDArray 4x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## do pixel 0,0

```
orig_indexes[0,0]  # row 0, column 0 = the first row index is in the first row column 0

[0.]
<NDArray 1 @cpu(0)>

[1]
<NDArray 1 @cpu(0)>

orig_image[new_indexes[0,0], new_indexes[0,1]]  # the new 0,0 pixel should be nine, pulled from 1,1

[1.]
<NDArray 1 @cpu(0)>
```

## Did a 1 move to pixel 0,0?

```
rotated_image[orig_indexes[0,0], orig_indexes[0,1]] = orig_image[new_indexes[0,0], new_indexes[0,1]]
rotated_image

[[1. 9.]
 [9. 9.]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## do pixel 0,1

```
rotated_image[orig_indexes[1,0], orig_indexes[1,1]] = orig_image[new_indexes[1,0], new_indexes[1,1]]
rotated_image

[[1. 3.]
 [9. 9.]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## Do pixel 1,0

```
rotated_image[orig_indexes[2,0], orig_indexes[2,1]] = orig_image[new_indexes[2,0], new_indexes[2,1]]
rotated_image

[[1. 3.]
 [0. 9.]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## do pixel 1,1

```
rotated_image[orig_indexes[3,0], orig_indexes[3,1]] = orig_image[new_indexes[3,0], new_indexes[3,1]]
rotated_image

[[1. 3.]
 [0. 2.]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## Is that rotated 90?

```
print('orig image', orig_image)
print('rotated_image', rotated_image)

orig image 
[[0. 1.]
 [2. 3.]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
rotated_image 
[[1. 3.]
 [0. 2.]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## Looks like it to me. I call that success, but not DFD success

####How to do this implicitly?

```
orig_image[new_indexes] # nope

[[[0. 1.]
  [2. 3.]]

 [[2. 3.]
  [2. 3.]]

 [[0. 1.]
  [0. 1.]]

 [[2. 3.]
  [0. 1.]]]
<NDArray 4x2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

## Hmm, try this contrib api again

```
# for reference
x = mx.nd.zeros((5,3))
t = mx.nd.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
index = mx.nd.array([0,4,2])  # <--- this is interesting. It has a zero length axes?????
# x is a template for output
# index is the indexes?
# t is "new_tensor?", its the source tensor?
mx.nd.contrib.index_copy(x, index, t)

[[1. 2. 3.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [4. 5. 6.]]
<NDArray 5x3 @cpu(0)>
```

That looks promising.  However, as i was copying my code to this question.  I realize the
problem.  The new_array, which is really a source array - fwiw in api param syntax its called `new_tensor`.  The index parameter is just to specify which rows of the source array are copied as is to the output array - api param parlanx `old_tensor`.  But not really the output array, to memory in the same shape as the "output array - old array in the api parameter syntax."  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

hmm.

## FWIW, here is how the nd.index_copy() routine works

I updated this section with more info on how this api works.  In hopes this api can do what I want.

```
template_tensor = nd.zeros([5,3])
template_tensor

[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
<NDArray 5x3 @cpu(0)>

source_indices = nd.array([0,2,4])
source_indices

[0. 2. 4.]
<NDArray 3 @cpu(0)>

source_tensor = nd.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])
source_tensor

[[0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 7. 8.]]
<NDArray 3x3 @cpu(0)>
```

This api uses the src_indices to specify which elements to copy from the source tensor to output. The output uses the template tensor for unspecified values misssing from the src_indices array.

```
nd.contrib.index_copy(template_tensor, source_indices, source_tensor)
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [6. 7. 8.]]
<NDArray 5x3 @cpu(0)>
```

Doing this again using the name parameter form

```
out_tensor = nd.ones([5,3])*9 # testing the out parameter with all nines

nd.contrib.index_copy(old_tensor=template_tensor,  # old_tensor is confusing  
           index_vector=source_indices,            # index_vector is not as confusing, but not clear 
           new_tensor=source_tensor,               # new_tensor is confusing.  Its not new nor is it modifed. 
           out=out_tensor,                         # using out paramter as foo, since not sure what it is ...
           name=None,)
```

results in

```
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [6. 7. 8.]]
<NDArray 5x3 @cpu(0)>
```

### Hmm, this shows that out_tensor is the name of the output.

So, what happens is all the values from the template_tensor is copied to the output, with the exception of the rows specified by the index_vector.  In that case, the values in the new_tensor
are are copied to output out_tensor

```
out_tensor
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [6. 7. 8.]]
<NDArray 5x3 @cpu(0)>
```

Comment: If it helps here is the original code  https://github.com/rtp-aws/devpost_aws_disaster_response/blob/main/python/gray_rotate_two.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

## This works for what I've tested

I would still like some comment to improve upon the answer though.  I'm certain it can be done better.  It also has an error with 270 rotate.  I've tested it with a 2x2 and 3x3 and rotates of 0,90, and 180

```
def my_rotate(input_image_batch, rotate_matrix, verbose=False):
    # NDArrayIter(data, label=None, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, 
    #            last_batch_handle='pad', data_name='data', 
    #            label_name='softmax_label')
    #
    # Ignore the label parameter.
    dataiter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(input_image_batch, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, last_batch_handle='discard')
    for batch in dataiter:

        my_print(verbose, 'loop entry - a single batch - a single image in batch.data[0] from what is in in_data')
        # Does this copy or get an alias to the input image?
        a_img_batch = batch.data[0]
        my_print(verbose, 'a_img_batch = ', a_img_batch)
        my_print(verbose, 'a_img_batch.shape = ', a_img_batch.shape)

        a_img_indexes = mx.nd.contrib.index_array(a_img_batch, axes=(1, 2))
        my_print(verbose, 'a_img_indexes  ', a_img_indexes)
        my_print(verbose, 'a_img_indexes.shape ', a_img_indexes.shape)



        # Try to assign input data to output data based upon indicies
        #
        # Need to reshape so that rows=size of image sans batch
        # 2x2-> 4,2
        # 3x3-> 9,2
        #
        num_rows = a_img_batch[0].size
        my_print(True,'num_rows = ', num_rows)
        orig_indexes = mx.nd.reshape(a_img_indexes, shape=(num_rows,2))
        my_print(verbose, 'orig_indexes ', orig_indexes)
        orig_indexes = orig_indexes.astype("float32")

        # do the rotate
        new_indexes = nd.dot(orig_indexes, rotate_matrix) 
        my_print(verbose, 'new_indexes = ', new_indexes)
        new_indexes = new_indexes.astype('int64')
        my_print(verbose, 'new_indexes = ', new_indexes)
        #
        # shift to lower right quadrant. shift so that index axes is 0,0 in top left
        #
        # find the min row value
        min_row = new_indexes.min(axis=0)[0]
        my_print(verbose, 'min_row = ', min_row)
        adj_row = nd.abs(min_row).asscalar()
        my_print(verbose, 'adj_row = ', adj_row)
        
        # find the min col value
        min_col = new_indexes.min(axis=0)[1]
        my_print(verbose, 'min_col = ', min_col)
        adj_col = nd.abs(min_col).asscalar()
        my_print(verbose, 'adj_col = ', adj_col)
        
        # adjust based upon min row/col
        # with rotate 90 for 3x3 its [0,2]
        new_indexes = new_indexes + nd.array(nd.array([adj_row, adj_col])).astype('int64')
        my_print(verbose, 'new_indexes after shift to positive', new_indexes)

        
        output_image_batch = nd.zeros(input_image_batch.size).reshape(input_image_batch.shape)
        output_image = output_image_batch[0]
        
        my_print(verbose, 'output_image_batch ', output_image_batch)
        my_print(verbose, 'output_image_batch.shape ', output_image_batch.shape)
        my_print(verbose, 'output_image_batch[0] ', output_image_batch[0])
        my_print(verbose, 'a_img_batch[0][new_indexes[:,0],new_indexes[:,1]] ', a_img_batch[0][new_indexes[:,0],new_indexes[:,1]])
        output_image = a_img_batch[0][new_indexes[:,0],new_indexes[:,1]]
        my_print(verbose, 'output_image ', output_image)
        # output_image is flatened, need to resize to rectangular
        new_dims = float(num_rows)**0.5
        new_dims = int(new_dims)
        output_image = output_image.reshape(new_dims,new_dims)
        my_print(verbose, 'output_image ', output_image)
        output_image_batch = nd.expand_dims(output_image, axis=0)
        my_print(verbose, 'output_image_batch ', output_image_batch)
        
        return output_image_batch
        #return 0 # stub
```

## Test 90 with 3x3

```
# Input Image 
in_img_batch = nd.arange(9).reshape((1,3,3))
print('in_img_batch is ', in_img_batch)
in_img = in_img_batch[0]
print('in_img ', in_img)

in_img_batch is  
[[[0. 1. 2.]
  [3. 4. 5.]
  [6. 7. 8.]]]
<NDArray 1x3x3 @cpu(0)>
in_img  
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 7. 8.]]
<NDArray 3x3 @cpu(0)>

out_img_batch = my_rotate(in_img_batch, rotate_90)
out_img_batch

('num_rows = ', 9)

[[[2. 5. 8.]
  [1. 4. 7.]
  [0. 3. 6.]]]
<NDArray 1x3x3 @cpu(0)>
```

## Test 90 with 2x2

```
# Input Image 
in_img_batch = nd.arange(4).reshape((1,2,2))
print('in_img_batch is ', in_img_batch)
in_img = in_img_batch[0]
print('in_img ', in_img)

in_img_batch is  
[[[0. 1.]
  [2. 3.]]]
<NDArray 1x2x2 @cpu(0)>
in_img  
[[0. 1.]
 [2. 3.]]
<NDArray 2x2 @cpu(0)>

out_img_batch = my_rotate(in_img_batch, rotate_90)
out_img_batch

('num_rows = ', 4)

[[[1. 3.]
  [0. 2.]]]
<NDArray 1x2x2 @cpu(0)>
```

Here is the notebook, if you wish to see the helper routines and imports.

https://github.com/rtp-aws/devpost_aws_disaster_response/blob/main/python/rotate_six.ipynb